# Directory ending with backslash can't be used for unattended mode on Windows system in install4j

Tags: install4j

When I use a installation directory ending with backslash to install something in unattended mode on Windows system

```
example.exe -q --sys.installationDir="C:\Program Files\test\" ....
```

, nothing get installed without any prompt.

But when I remove the trailing backslash, it works correctly.

```
example.exe -q --sys.installationDir="C:\Program Files\test" ....
```

It's weird that the directory ending with backslash works well for GUI mode on windows system.

Is there any requirement that the installation directory can't end with backslash for unattended mode on Windows system?

Why are there different requirements for directory formats between unattended mode and GUI mode for windows system?

Answer (score 0):

Do not quote like this:

```
param="value"
```

but like this:

```
"param=value"
```

Also, the command line option for setting the installation directory is "-dir":

```
example.exe -q - dir "C:\Program Files\test"
```

Comment: Actually, I use `context.getExtraCommandLineArguments()` to parse the param. The actual command is like `example.exe -q --installation.dir="C:\Program Files\test\" ....`. I found `getExtraCommandLineArguments()` will parse the trailing backslash to an escape character in `--installation.dir="C:\Program Files\test\"`, the parsed string will be `--installation.dir=C:\Program Files\test" ...`(there's an extra double quotation), and the param list will be parsed to one long string, which causes the installation failed. Is it a bug for `getExtraCommandLineArguments()`` OR is it intentional?

Comment: This escaping is done by the shell, the install4j runtime does not replace escape sequences in arguments